# Missing Property in Visual Studio 2017 Community RichTextBox

Tags: vb.net

Win 7, VS 2017 Community, Framework 4.6.1, RichTextBox Version 4.6.1.0

I am using a RichTextBox and am trying to center the RichTextBox, both Horizontally and Vertically, in a Panel.  However, the RichTextBox control is missing the property ClientSize. MicroSoft documentation shows the property exists. I am totally lost and welcome help.

A single or Multiline TextBox.Text has been placed 
 in the  RichTextBox prior to calling this routine

```
Private Sub CenterRtb()
    Dim LineSize As SizeF
    Dim RtbW As Single     ' RichTextBox Width
    Dim RtbH As Single     ' RichTextBox Height
    Dim LocX As Integer
    Dim LocY As Integer

    ' Find Longest Line and Total Height Of Lines
    RtbW = 0
    RtbH = 0
    For Each Line As String In rtbText.Lines
```

cMetrics is predefined class for measuring Text strings using g.MeasureText

```
        LineSize = cMetrics.Metrics.GetTexTSize(Line, rtbText.Font)

        If (LineSize.Width > RtbW) Then RtbW = LineSize.Width
        RtbH = RtbH + LineSize.Height
    Next
```

Note:  Would Prefer ClientSize rather than  RichTextBox physical size.

```
    ' Adjust For RichTextBox Actual Size
    If (RtbW > rtbText.Width) Then RtbW = rtbText.Width
    If (RtbH > rtbText.Height) Then RtbH = rtbText.Height - 10

    rtbText.Width = CInt(RtbW)
    rtbText.Height = CInt(RtbH + 20)

    LocX = CInt((pnlRtb.Width - rtbText.Width) / 2)
    LocY = CInt((pnlRtb.Height - rtbText.Height) / 2)
    rtbText.Location = New Point(LocX, LocY)
End Sub
```

Comment: `ClientSize`, as `ClientRectangle`, is inherited from `System.Windows.Forms.Control`. The [EditorBrowsable Attribute](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs,1607) is `EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)`

Comment: It doesn't mean that the property is not there, though. Even if Intellisense doesn't show it.

Comment: Thanks Jimi.  I tried it without depending on intellisense and all is fine.  Question answered.  I wonder why the property doesn't show in intellisense.

Comment: `EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)` is used exactly for this: it hides *advanced* members if the user has not disabled `Hide advanced members` in the Text Editor options. No idea whether this option is available in the Community Edition of VS.

Comment: Hi Jimi:  The Hide advanced members is available.  It is checked and  cannot be un-checked.  BTW:  Dumped the above code and simplified using TextRenderer.MesaureText snd ClientSize.  Thanks for the help, it is appreciated.